# Windows Batch File Iterator Problem

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have 3 projects that I use svn for them. My folder system is that: There is a folder `projects`, within projects folder there are 3 projects `projectA`, `projectB` and `projectC`.

I have a Windows batch script code like that:

```
d:
cd projectA
svn update
cd ../projectB
svn update
cd ../projectC
svn update
```

The purpose of it with one .bat file I want to update all of my projects. That code seems like can be improved. Is it possible to change it like:

```
set folder=projects
set directories=(projectA projectB projectC)
set command=svn update
d:
for %%i in %directories% do cd.. && cd %folder%/%%i && %command%
```

That code fails on somewhere. It should be change to do while loop or something like that because it tries to make `cd projects\projectB` while it is under projects folder (It should be at upper folder of projects to execute cd projects\etc.)

**EDIT:** @Andriy M There is a screenshot from my computer. Red is projectA, blue is projectB and purple is projectC.

Here it:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you see the error message after the `folder` assignment line? It's the reason why you have different path in the following loop. The path is different because the top assignment didn't work and `folder` has the value you assigned it previously. Your text editor has probably saved the batch file in UTF-8 encoding, and the first three bytes of the file are most probably UTF-8 signature, judging from the screenshot. But the shell doesn't recognise them as such, tries to interpret them and fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What prevents you from implementing it like this:

```
SET folder=D:\fullpath\project
SET directories=(projectA projectB projectC)
SET command=svn update
FOR %%i IN %directories% DO (CD /D %folder%\%%i && %command%)
```

?

Comment: I set the folder name as d:\projects\projectA but it tries to do: cd projects\projectA instead of putting d:\ beginning of it.

Comment: @kamaci: Not sure. By the way, `folder` is supposed to be the parent folder for your projects, so may be you should store `d:\projects` into it. Still that doesn't explain why the drive part is dropped from the path. It worked fine when I tested it. Are you sure you applied it correctly?

Comment: @kamaci - are you sure you didn't miss the `/D` after `CD`?

Comment: It would be nice to learn how to change my code to work but your answer is OK. Thanks Andriy.